# Does isomorphism between direct product of groups imply an isomorphism between groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, abelian-groups

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be finite abelian groups satisfying the property
$$A\times B \cong A\times C$$
Does it follow that $B\cong C$?

---

There exists a multiplicative bijection $\phi: A\times B \rightarrow A\times C$. Let $(a, c), (a', c')\in A\times C$, then by the injectivity of $\phi$,
$\phi(a, c) = \phi(a', c')$ if and only if $a = a'$, $c = c'$. By the surjectivity of $\phi$, we know for every $(a, c)\in A\times C$ there exists $(a, b)\in B$ such that $\phi(a, b) = (a, c)$. And finally, by the multiplicative property, $\phi(ac, bd) = \phi(a, b)\cdot \phi(c, d)$

But I don't see any connection that there must be an isomorphism $\mu$ between $B$ and $C$. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is true in general when the groups are finite. A proof may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427640/10513). (I suggest not closing this question as a duplicate yet, incase someone types out a slick proof for the abelian case.)

Comment: @user1729 There are many duplicates for every single variation of this question. Another post, with more background, is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257259/for-groups-a-b-c-if-a-times-b-and-a-times-c-are-isomorphic-do-we-have-b), but there are really many, many such posts. In particular, there are posts giving nice proofs for the fact that finite abelian groups are cancellable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was unable to find an abelian-specific one, so thanks for digging one up! (I actually don't like the proof there - surely it can be done without reference to the FTFAG?!)

Comment: @user1729 I will check the "other nine" posts on finite abelian groups, whether or not they use the structure theorem. The [next one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227812/the-cancellation-property-for-finite-abelian-groups) uses it more or less, too. [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27667/for-finite-abelian-groups-show-that-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-implies-g-c), too. May be in the end, the elementary proof you have linked is better? The proof by [Hirshon](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/hirshon/cancel/cancel.pdf) is often cited.

Comment: @user1729 More posts about the (finitely generated) abelian case are [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744670/cancellation-for-finitely-generated-abelian-groups) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186770/for-finitely-generated-abelian-groups-a-and-b-prove-that-a-oplus-a-simeq?noredirect=1&lq=1). The last one is by myself (surprise). It looks rather short, but I fear you still don't like it :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was just being picky, but now I'm slightly interested. My brain is busy elsewhere this week, but maybe I'll think about a simple FTFAG-based proof when it returns.